# Calculating Canopy Cover percentage in buffer using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, nlcd

I am trying to calculate percent canopy cover within a buffer for each site I have. Here are the steps I took.

1. I used the tabulate area function with the canopy cover layer to get the area for each location
2. I added up rows 3-74 to get total canopy (I excluded row 2 from this part since the value is zero which would mean that there isn't any canopy from what I interpreted). To get the total area I added row 2 to the total canopy number.
3. I divided total canopy by the total area to get the percent canopy for each site.

By using the tabulate area function I think the numbers for each row should be meters squared.

Is this correct?

Comment: The units are square whatever your coordinate system unit is.. if you have data in geographic coordinates it's square degrees, projected units could be inches, feet or metres depending on your projected coordinate system.

Comment: Thank you. Adding the meters together from each Value would be the total area, correct?

Comment: Yes, the sum of all the parts is the total coverage. You should be able to divide the sum of canopy cover by the area of each polygon to find your percentage as a decimal, multiply by 100 to express as a traditional percentage.